# Keyboard shortcut in Xcode to delete constraint instead of uninstalling it?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

When I select a view in interface builder and highlight a constraint in utilities, how can I delete it? Pressing 'delete' just uninstalls the constraint.. I can delete it by highlighing it in the Document Outline and pressing delete there but I would love to have a way to delete it from this view.

[image: Selected constraint]

Comment: You can delete it and uninstall it simultaneously by selecting the constraint in the Library of views sidebar and pressing delete or backspace. But you can't do it for the inspectors tab as your trying to do

Comment: I need a way to do without having to deselect the currently selected view..

Comment: As with all these tools, my guess is that Apple engineers aren´t really using them, so that is probably the easiest way. The way I´ve been doing this is double click on constraint and then press delete.

Comment: Don't forget you can always create custom keyboard shortcuts in system preferences

Comment: @soulshined, how would I go about doing that for this situation? Can you outline the steps for that in an answer?

Comment: Sure. If someone hasn't beaten me to the punch I'll offer an answer when I get home from work. Technically not supposed to be on here ;)

Answer (score 1):

Kris,

I quickly and vaguely was able to successfully create an automator service and assigning it to an Xcode custom keyboard shortcut <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> using a, again quickly assembled, custom applescript:

```
tell application "System Events"
    #keystroke instead of key code for this instance ASCII character for backspace (delete)
    keystroke (ASCII character 8)
    delay 0.1
    # delay ensures the system has enough time to process the first task and then repeats the button keystroke
    keystroke (ASCII character 8)
end tell
```

However, it seems that Apple has blocked further editing for constraints once they are uninstalled fromm the inspectors tab (e.g, they are no longer selectable in the attributes/inspector tab since you uninstalled. Makes sense, but also impractical)

To circumvent the whole double click button to delete method you could still delete the constraint with the forward delete button <kbd>delete⌦</kbd> under your <kbd>fn</kbd> button for full-sized keyboards or the regular <kbd>delete</kbd> button while reviewing all the constraints for your selected view in the 'Document Outline' side bar. Delete it directly from that sidebar by pressing the forward delete button or regular delete once. It will uninstall and delete simultaneously:

[image: pic1]

The downside, is you have to find the constraint manually by either cross-referencing the constraint type icon to the one selected in the inspector tab or by manually renaming the constraints to something identifiable (who really wants to do that) or by doing what @Pahnev suggested in the inspector tab double clicking the constraint, which takes you directly to the Documents Outline constraint and press delete. Either option takes you away from the main View's constraints. *Sorry this doesn't answer your question*, but you should submit a grief report or feature request to Apple if it's worth your time or consider it a serious enough flaw to invest that time to.

It also states in the 'Edit' menu that command+delete will uninstall the constraint, but thats not the case from the inspectors tab (which was my problem with the applescript) it's only true if you select the specific constraint either from the documents outline or the double click method, else it will ask you if you want to delete the storyboard.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and research. This issue is relatively new as I remember it working the right way on previous versions of Xcode. Perhaps future versions will have a an easy way to do this so I'll leave this question open til then. You earned an upvote tho.

Comment: @KrisJurgowski sorry it didn't answer your question - I was looking forward to using it myself. Maybe submit a radar

Answer (score 0):

Just use my simple gem https://github.com/kohtenko/KOConstraintClean It will clean all your unwanted constraints